# Does Javascript have a BasicObject similar to Ruby?

Tags: javascript, ruby

In Ruby, in order to get the absolute cleanest inheritance chain, you can inherit from `BasicObject` instead of `Object`.  This way you don't have an object with methods you don't necessarily want (the methods that are part of `Object.prototype`).

Does JavaScript have a similar means of defining a basic object?

```
function Person(name){
    this.name = name
}
var mac = new Person('Mac')
delete mac.toString        //does not work
delete mac.hasOwnProperty  //does not work
```

Once you instantiate an object via a constructor function, it is not possible to `delete` properties from the object if those properties are actually methods found on the prototype.

I don't want these methods on my object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an object with no properties at all by calling `Object.create(null)`.

You can then set that as a function's `prototype`.
(instead of the default prototype, which starts as `Object.create(Object.prototype)`.